# CSV formatted data off website not being properly parsed

Tags: python, csv

My Python script opens a file through urllib2; the data looks like this:

```
"Charitable Donation: Contribution","012","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

The Python script:

```
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

The output is this:

```
['Charitable Donation: Contribution']
['', '']
['012']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
['', '']
['']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you are asking. What is your definition of "useful?"

Comment: the `C` in `CSV` stands for `COMMA` use that as your separator, not `"`

Comment: -1: The output shown does not come from the code shown.

Answer (score 3):

You're using double-quote (`"`) as the delimiter instead of comma (`,`) ...*why?* How about

```
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for row in reader:
    print row

# you can omit the delimiter argument as well, since comma is the default:
reader = csv.reader(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
# etc.
```

Comment: (-1) Did you test your code?  It gives the exact same output as the OP on Python 2.7.

Comment: No, it most certainly does not.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand: Matt answered before the OP had edited his question to show a *completely* different `csv.reader()` call.

Comment: ...bollocks. Thanks @Tim. _grumble, grumble, question edits..._

Answer (score 2):

you want the comma to be the delimiter as the delimiter is what seperates values.
the quotechar is " as it is what values are contained in.

try

```
reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Comment: (-1) Did you test your code? It gives the exact same output as the OP on Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter is an iterator.  In the example [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader), they use a file object.  Iterating a string gives each character, but you want just the line.  The simplest fix is to make `data` a list.

```
reader = csv.reader([data])
for row in reader:
    print row
```

It gives the output:

```
['Charitable Donation: Contribution', '012', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure about the delimiter or quoting parameters, so I left them as is.  It still gives the expected output, but feel free to correct me on that.

Comment: This is what I get when i make it into a list                        _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: I believe I edited while you were typing.  It should work now.  [ideone](http://ideone.com/77KkE)

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the wrong delimiter - you should use `','` and have then to take care for the fact that the parts you get are quoted.